# Automate notification to Mailchimp

Tags: 8, nodes, emails

I am trying to automate a notification integration between Drupal8 and Mailchimp.

I currently the Mailchimp module installed and a signup form has been configured so that people can signup for notifications and select which 'Group' they wish to be part off.

However, I am now trying to automate the notification process. So that the process will be like this:

1. An article created which has the 'Sports' and 'NFL' taxonomy selected,
2. The article is published,
3. Send notification to Mailchimp that a 'Sports' and 'NFL' article has been published,
4. Mailchimp will send a notification email to all users who are part of either the 'Sports' or 'NFL' groups in our mailing list. The notification email will include a link to the relevant article.

I have searched for a module for the above but haven't found anything. Is there an already built solution for the above? Or should I be writing a custom module and/or using the Rules module?

Comment: I don't know the Mailchimp API but why don't you simply send the mail from Drupal?

Comment: Initially, we decided to send through Mailchimp because their emails are sent from a no-reply address and Mailchimp handles the unsubscribe functionality.

If we sent from Drupal, I'm assuming that we would have to fetch the Mailchimp API the emails who belong to that particular group and send them out?

Comment: I am looking for this answer as well. I found something similar for WordPress: https://mailoptin.io/article/new-post-notification-mailchimp-email-list/ and Drupal 8 does have a MailChimp module (https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp). There is even a MailChimp Webform module (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mailchimp). I feel like the solution is somewhere in there.